# Add specific media types to iTunes without copying them to the iTunes Media Folder?

Tags: itunes

I have some media that I'd like to stream to my AppleTV that's quite transient. I don't need it in my iTunes Media Folder proper for more than one viewing of the media. Is it possible to have iTunes *not* copy *specific* media types to the iTunes Media Folder when I import it in to iTunes? In this case, I'd rather iTunes didn't copy and automatically organize video media when I import it. But I'm okay if it copies and automatically organizes audio media when I import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down option whilst dragging into the ITunes window to add to the library, without it also being copied into ITunes fodler